# Capturing @@error and @@rowcount from a single query

Tags: t-sql

This seems like it should be pretty simple, but I cannot find a way to do it.

```
set nocount on;

Update MyTable
set MyField = 'value'
--where 1 = 1/0 -- comment in to test getting an error.

print convert(varchar, @@error)
print "blah blah" + convert(nvarchar, @@rowcount) -- this is always zero because of the previous statement
```

I tried storing them in a variable, but setting the variable generates a new @@rowcount and new @@error value.

I also tried using an if condition, because i don't care about the row count.  But evaluating the if seems to also reset @@rowcount.

Comment: This changes depending on what platform you are working in.  So which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a single statement, like this:

```
DECLARE @err INT, @cnt INT
SELECT @err=@@ERROR, @cnt=@@ROWCOUNT
```